# Create global var in .ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, inappbrowser

Currently I need to add an event to browser inside the CheckSocialMedia function. However it says could not find name.

So how do I make the 'browser' variable global in the .ts file? I have tried some things but nothing is working. Thanks

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserOptions } from "@ionic-native/in-app-browser";
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AppAvailability } from '@ionic-native/app-availability';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    public browser: object//doesn't work

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser, public platform: Platform, private appAvailability: AppAvailability)
  {
      //options for iab
      const options: InAppBrowserOptions = 
      {
          toolbar: 'no',
          location: 'no',
          zoom: 'no'
      }

      //when device rdy
     this.platform.ready().then( () => {

         browser = this.inAppBrowser.create("https://www.awebsite.co.uk/", '_blank', options);
            browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(event => { this.CheckSocialMediaLinks(event.url); });
     })

  }

  //check if link is for social media
  CheckSocialMediaLinks(url: string){ //I need to resubscribe the event
      const watch = browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(event => { this.CheckSocialMediaLinks(event.url); });
}
```

Comment: Is that a variable that's already declared in another script? If so `declare var browser: any;` outside of the class should work. If not, `public browser: any`

Comment: First: global variables are **bad**. But have you tried accessing `window.browser` ?

Comment: @baao no its not declared in another script. I tried public browser: any but it still gives me an error: typescript: C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Ionic/Example/src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 29
            Cannot find name 'browser'.

      L29:  browser = this.inAppBrowser.create("https://www.awebsite.co.uk/", '_blank', options);

Comment: @LorenzMerdian I tried that, gives me an error: typescript: C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Ionic/Example/src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 36
            Property 'browser' does not exist on type 'Window'.

Comment: @LorenzMerdian solved the error and made browser a window property, the build succeeded, testing now, will report back.

Comment: If you solved it like that, rearrange your code. You don't want to do that like that

Comment: @baao I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: You'd have a global variable, and you don't want to have that usually. You might be better of using a service or provider that provides whatever `browser` should b.

Comment: @baao Oh okay, thanks. Someone answered with some info on that, will give it a read in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Globals, in general, is bad and it's an anti-pattern in Ionic, the best practice is to use provider where to store all global variables and use this provider in components where needed those globals.
Take a look at this discussion and Mike answer. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/global-variables-on-ionic-2/45890/7?u=tomstumshais

Or one more example how to solve this global's problem.
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-change-value-of-global-variable-on-any-files-in-ionic/103294/5?u=tomstumshais